# How to set the Android Studio code analyzer to not return thousands of spelling errors?

Tags: android-studio

I'm using the Android Studio (AS) 3.3.2 to try to revive an old project. 
Running `Analyze > Inspect code...` unexpectedly returns a huge number of spelling errors (~8000) for just about everything, not distinguishing between what is code, comments, or XML attributes, etc.

In previous projects, I never encountered this problem and it seems that AS was smart enough to separate code, variables, etc when spell checking. Now it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are also other problems. For example with properties files found in both Gradle cache and seemingly from build intermediates:

```
..\\app\\build\\intermediates\\res\\merged\\debug\\drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17_abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha.png.flat
```

I have also tried to `disable 'Typos'` in the `app/build.gradle` under `lintOptions{}` without any effect. (It seem that this is ignored.)

**How can I tune this to behave in a sane way?**
(I don't want to turn off spell checking.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**"URI is not registered"** could be for a few reasons such as:

- you have added manually `activity_emergency_number.xml` while being in a specific `build variant` and it could have been missing some linking configurations for other build variants. A solution here is to try to switch build variants to make Android Studio reload configuration linking.
- Misleading linking between resources in your Intellij Idea cache. A solution could be to `Invalidate and Restart Cache`.
- The `folder structure` of where activity_emergency_number.xml is located
- Add your url through `Preferences > Languages & Frameworks > Schemas and DTDs > Add(+) > Apply > Ok`
- activity_emergency_number.xml missing header line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
- When you have `multiple flavors`, make sure that your current selected build variant matches the flavor for the layout activity_emergency_number.xml
- your `attributes` in activity_emergency_number.xml views are missing some `prefix` like `android:` or have some prefix that aren't needed fr those attributes

**About ignoring some spelling typo** in situations such as code variables and not ignoring them in other situations such as comments, you have those options available to tune together as well with the Scope you are interested (Production, Test, Project Source Files, Project Files..) in:

`Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Spelling > Typo`

Here you have two things:

- `Severity` (where you define also the Scope)
- `Options`

  - `Process Code` (unselect this to not check typos in code variables)
  - `Process Literal` (this one you have to try if you will need it)
  - `Process Comments` (keep this selected to check typos in comment)

[image]

Comment: The path to that file is: `./app/src/main/res/layout/activity_emergency_number.xml`. Also I do use build variants. What do you mean when you say *"being in a specific build variant"* and *"your current selected build variant matches the flavor..."*?

Comment: Actually, I'm starting to think there is a bug with AS, as after having re-imported the project in various ways, I finally got down the spell checking to only 87 typos. It is still annoying though, that when declaring a variable like this: **`private static final double COEF_X = 1.0;`** leads to a spelling error for `COEF_X`. That is just dumb. I would have agreed if the variable was never used or present elsewhere, but when it is used in the code, it should not be flagged as a spelling error.

Comment: Dynamics like misleading errors/warnings/lint functionality in IntellijIdea with Android Studio have always been there due to some state/cache bugs that triggers functionality in the wrong way. Your solution to re-importing the project in different ways define that Android Studio some times doesn't behave as expected and some state are not being restored with just Restart and Invalidate Cache. Glad you had it down by that number now